# Javascript date formatting Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013 to iso 8601 (2013-06-21)

Tags: javascript

Please advise:

Is there a  way without regex or string replaces and so forth to convert a simple date such as:

```
Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013
```

To a ISO`8601` formatted date  `yy-mm-dd`?

PS: `8601` date only, not date time.

Comment: Without regular expressions or string replacement?  What would you like to use instead?

Comment: I wondered if there was a C# esque  format...
albeit at this point any method will do, i'm getting fed up of trying numerous regex replaces of which i'm not very good with!

Comment: Is your starting date (Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013) just a string or is it a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object?

Comment: As an aside, that's a weird input format: I don't recall ever (before) seeing a date/time format that puts the time part in the _middle_ of the date parts.

Comment: It's just a string at this point, i'm using knockout and trying to write a custom binding... and failing at this part :P

The string is coming from select event: datepicker (jquyeryUI)

Comment: @JoshuaHolden: You should be able to tell datepicker to give you the date in the format you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regexes or string replaces? Yes, assuming that the format is fixed you could use `.slice()` and/or `.substr()` to extract the particular bits you need and rearrange them (unless such methods fall into your category of "and so forth"):

```
var input = "Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013";

var year = input.slice(-4),
    month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
             'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'].indexOf(input.substr(4,3))+1,
    day = input.substr(8,2);

var output = year + '-' + (month<10?'0':'') + month + '-' + day;
```

Or you *could* go ahead and get silly with a regex replace:

```
var output = input.replace(/^[^\s]+\s([^\s]+)\s(\d+)\s.*(\d{4})$/,function(m,p1,p2,p3) {
   var month = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'].indexOf(p1)+1;
   return p3 + '-' + (month<10?'0':'') + month + '-' + (p2.length===1?'0':'') + p2;
});
```

Of course you'd probably want to wrap such code in a `reformatDate()` method.

(For a "simple" reformatting of a date *string,* the `Date` object and its methods aren't particularly helpful unless the starting format is one recognised by [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).)

Comment: Even though, it's exactly what I didn't want this worked best for me.

*cheers*

Comment: Yes, I suggested this against your wishes because (in my opinion) it is the simplest way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5):

Use moment.js http://momentjs.com/

```
moment(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
```

or:

```
var date = moment("Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013");
moment("Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
```

You can parse it and format it very easily whatever way you want http://momentjs.com/docs/ it is compatible with ISO-8601 dates for parsing as well.

Comment: thanks,
I have had a play with moment now and it's brilliant. I'm trying to keep down my external library count though as I already have 12 external ones, weighing in at 80kb on my base page load (SPA)

Answer (score 4):

Yes !

the date function in javascript.

```
var d = new Date("Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013")
alert( d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getUTCMonth() + '-' + d.getUTCDay())
```

2 lines of code :)

more info here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Missing + before the getDay after the '-'

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try to use the `get` functions, like `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, etc. For example:

```
var today = new Date();
var d1 = new Date();
alert(d1);
var date = d1.getDate();
var month = d1.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d1.getFullYear();
```

Then configure the string the way you want it to appear...!

Comment: Because I have to assign the date string:
    Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2013

to a date before I can do such things, how would I assign this string to be a date

Comment: @JoshuaHolden: Did you read the documentation for `Date` yet? Why not?